# How to get posts in backbone where a custom field matches a value?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, backbone

How can I retrieve posts, using backbone, that match a particular custom field value?

My custom fields are created through ACF.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
var data = {
    offset: 0, 
    _embed: 1,
    per_page: 100,
    _fields: "_embedded,_links,id,acf,title",
    meta_key: "status",
    meta_value: "new"
};
                                        
postsCollection
    .fetch({ data: data })
```

Comment: I posted an answer, but are you sure you don't want to use a custom taxonomy, because for example you could use a taxonomy named `status`, and then you would be able to easily filter the posts via the `tax_relation` parameter in the REST API, without having to use the filter hooks stated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I realised I could do this via a taxonomy, too. Though this would require converting the existing data structure and parts of the frontend, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API endpoint "List Posts" (e.g. [`GET /wp/v2/posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts)) does not support filtering the posts by a post meta (or custom field), therefore passing [post meta parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) like `meta_key` and `meta_value` will by default do nothing.

But the [`rest_<post type>}_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) can be used to manually add custom meta queries to the query arguments passed to `WP_Query`.

Here's an example for the core `post` type, but validation and sanitization is up to you…

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'my_filter_rest_post_query', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_rest_post_query( $args, $request ) {
    if ( isset( $request['meta_key'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = $request['meta_key'];

        // If the request did not include the meta_value parameter, or that it's a
        // null, then we do not set the meta_value argument. Which means, the API
        // response would include any posts that have the meta, regardless the value.
        if ( isset( $request['meta_value'] ) ) {
            $args['meta_value'] = $request['meta_value'];
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

So with that, your Backbone code should now work, but a better option, which makes use of the [core validation functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#json-schema-basics), where validation is by default done automatically for you, is by *registering your custom request parameter* using the [`rest_<post type>_collection_params` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/).

Here's an example where I used a single custom parameter named `meta_status` for your `status` meta:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'my_filter_rest_post_collection_params' );
function my_filter_rest_post_collection_params( $query_params ) {
    $query_params['meta_status'] = array(
        'anyOf' => array(
            array( 'type' => 'string' ),
            array( 'type' => 'null' ), // Allows a real null value.
        ),
        // Your other arguments here.
    );

    return $query_params;
}
```

Now the filter callback might look like:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'my_filter_rest_post_query', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_rest_post_query( $args, $request ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'meta_status', $request->get_params() ) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'status';

        // I've allowed a null value, therefore, if the meta_value parameter is a
        // null, then we do not set the meta_value argument. Which means, the API
        // response would include any posts that have the meta, regardless the value.
        if ( isset( $request['meta_status'] ) ) {
            $args['meta_value'] = $request['meta_status'];
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```